# Changing guitar chords from the key of flat

Tags: guitar, chords, acoustic-guitar

I have a song with chords cm-fm-G7-cm-cm-fm-Bb-Eb-fm-G7-cm-Bb-Ab-fm-G-Ab-G7-cm
and the chorus is fm-Bb7-Eb-cm/Eb-fm6-cm/Eb-D-G

These are pretty difficult to play on guitar and i was wondering what could i do to make these chords easier to play on the guitar either with capo or changing the key slightly.... Please help.

Comment: I would just voice them to be more easy. Like play B chords up the neck a bit and only use the middle four strings.

Comment: I've never heard of "the key of flat"...

Answer (score 1):

The 'b' you mention may actually be Bb in the original.  I've heard that in some countries B is Bb (I don't know whether this is still the case) so that's a possibility here.

You can capo the third fret and finger the chords as (I'm assuming the Bb):

Am Dm E7 Am 
Am Dm G  C
Dm E7 Am G F
Dm E F E7 Am

Dm G C Am/C Dm6 Cm/C B E

It may help to play the final B and E as 7 chords.

I'm not a particularly skilled guitarist but I could manage these chords pretty easily as bar chords.  You may want to look those up for consideration.  A hard-to-play acoustic might be a bit tough but I think that you can do it.  If the bar chords are hard, have a look at voicing differently (as Todd Wilcox suggested).  If you're finger picking you can play a root in the bottom (except where otherwise noted during the chorus) and 3 notes somewhere above -- for a seventh you can skip the root in the upper notes and instead play the 3rd, 5th, and 7th.

Answer (score 1):

In key, that B should be played as a Bb. The G# will be Ab. Now, all the chords come from C minor. The numbers for them are Cm=I. D=II. Eb=III. Fm=IV. G=V. Ab=VI. Bb=VII. I've put Roman numerals in caps for simplicity.

Now the sequence is -

```
I, IV, V, I;     I, IV, VII, III;      IV, V, I, VI;     IV, V, VI, V;    I.
```

Just about any key will give at least one problematic chord, but now, you can use the formula to find the chords in any key. A minor wouldn't be too bad, with Am B C Dm E F and G. Em would work, with Em F# G Am B and C. But there is always going to be an awkward to play chord somewhere. Using barres totally will make playing easier - but only if you play barre chords well.

Answer (score 0):

Those are some crazy chord progressions, you could down-tune to eb standard and that would make your eb chord open and more accessible and then move all your chords up 1/2 step or 1 fret.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it down a half step (~ down one fret). That would be this:

bm-em-F#7-bm-bm-em-A-D-em-F#7-bm-A-G-em-F#-G-F#7-bm

em-A7-D-bm/D-em6-bm/D-C#-F#

If you're singing along to this song changing the key down a half step is probably still within your range. The C# chord could be played C#7 instead if that's easier. As a side note I think it makes it a lot easier to read the progression if you show the chord quality with the case of the letter. Also spelling counts! G# isn't the same thing as Ab. And following the lead of some other answers, I take your original B chords to be Bb chords.

Comment: On most instruments, G# is the same as Ab. However, naming it Ab in this situation is correct - or is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I meant that it matters conceptually, not that it would be tuned differently.

Comment: You could also just put the capo on fret 1 and you would play the same chord voicings.  Then, as too many guitar players do, you could still refer to the Cm that is being played as a Bm (because it is the shape of a Bm with no capo).  Second sentence is just to be snarky, feel free to disregard.